# ASP.net Web page with Google Map is not loading inside phonegap

Tags: asp.net, cordova

I have an working asp.net web page with google map .My requirement is ,i want to show the same asp.net webpage in iphone as native appiication.for that i loaded the same page  inside phonegap [PhoneGap is an HTML5 app platform that allows you to author native applications with web technologies] but its showing a white screen with zoom  controls and map-satellite-hybrid option also...but map is not showing just a white screen is showing...

Answer (score 0):

Does the same app runs correctly inside Mobile Safari? Check if this is a limitation of Mobile Safari or PhoneGap.

Comment: Thanks For reply...yes its perfectly working on safari...and its showing a whitescreen with zall goole map controls[zoom and map sattelite] controls also see in phonegap...